# Is the following sentence correct to decline a invitation?

Tags: grammar

あ、実は今日、会議があっているんですよ。

This as an answer for an invitation to do something today. Also the dialog I'm talking about is over the phone.

Comment: I think this site wants you to ask a question regarding a particular language topic, rather than "Is my Japanese correct?" (Nonetheless: あっているんですよ → あるんですよ)

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking if this is the correct way to decline an invitation, then yeah you can say that you have a meeting today as a way of saying "no I'm busy".

If you're asking if your sentence is grammatically correct, then no, not completely. While あっている is used in some dialects, it's not standard Japanese so you should probably use ある.

Answer (score 0):

If you decline someone's invitation due to another plan such as a dialog.

In a formal way, you can say the following sentence.

"会議の予定が入っているため、申し訳ありませんがお断りさせていただきます。"

In a bit casual way, you can say the following sentences.

"あ、実は今日会議が入ってるんですよね。"

"あ、実は今日会議があるんですよね。"

Although this is a casual form, you can use this in the conversation with your colleagues.

Comment: It doesn't really have anything to do with the question though